# Eevee alpha texture shadow issue

Tags: texturing, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have a problem with shadows when I use the alpha channel textures. I've noticed this issue is on my 2 PC with AMD and Radeon video cards. On 3 PC with Intel and GeForce I don't have this kind of issues. 
In Cycle all works like it should, I have issue only when using the eevee. 
Does anyone know why there is such a problem with Radion video cards and if there is a solution to it?
I have the latest drivers on my PCs

screenshots
Cycle
[image]

Eevee
[image]
[image]